# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: namespace name generated from index name is too long

Tags: django, aws-documentdb, djongo

I know the index name is too long, `django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq`, but this is auto genarate by django makemigrations, so how to edit and contral this long index name? TKS!

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: namespace name generated from index name is too long, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'code': 67, 'errmsg': 'namespace name generated from index name is too long', 'operationTime': Timestamp(1677686036, 1)}

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 869, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError: 

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: ALTER TABLE "django_content_type" ADD CONSTRAINT "django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq" UNIQUE ("app_label", "model")
        Params: ()
        Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError
```

Comment: Are you migrating to Amazon DocumentDB? Do you have an option to skip index creation with django makemigration? I'm thinking you can use the index tool (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-documentdb-tools/tree/master/index-tool) to pre-create the indexes on target and then just move data.